# Community User not receiving welcome email from sandbox

Tags: apex, community, email

Community users are not receiving their welcome email when testing a custom self registration form in a sandbox org.

**Current setup**

1. The custom community user login profile has been configured in the `workspace > administration > members` section
2. The `Welcome New Member` email template is configured
3. The `Send Welcome email` checkbox is selected
4. The email template is `Available For Use`
5. The community is `Active`
6. System email deliverability is `All email`

When we use the custom self registration form, it successfully creates the `Person Account` and `User` records, but no welcome email is sent.

The custom self registration form uses the below code to create the account and user:

```
public without sharing class SignupService 

    public Boolean createAccount(SignupParams params) {

        // creates the SObject, but does not insert
        User user = createUser(params); 

        // creates the SObject, but does not insert
        Account person = createAcccount(params); 
        insert person;

        String userId = Site.createExternalUser(user, person.Id, params.password);

        return true;
    }
}
```

**Questions**

1. Why is the email not being sent?
2. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. You're not setting the parameter to send the email in the method `createExternalUser` and **it seems the default is set to false to not send.**
2. The [Site Class docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_sites.htm) show that you should be able to send the email by adding a 4th parameter of `true`:

```
createExternalUser(user, accountId, password, sendEmailConfirmation)
```

[image]