# Community user does not receive email from scratch org

Tags: community, customer-community, scratch-org, experience-cloud

I'm developing a customer portal via DX and scratch orgs. Currently, portal user doesn't receive forgot and change password email.

- Send welcome email checkbox is checked
- Deliverability Access level set to All email

But if I try to change admin account password through community, then admin receives email.

What could be a reason?

Comment: Have you checked with this similar [question](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/298990/community-user-not-receiving-welcome-email-from-sandbox)?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your community is activated and out of preview mode and this should fix the issue. The site was defaulted to preview mode when it was created. I had a similar issue.